# How can I convert my Tarkov USD into EUR efficiently?

Tags: escape-from-tarkov

The Peacekeeper quests gave me plenty **USD**, conveniently about 50000. The last quest [Mentor](https://escapefromtarkov.fandom.com/wiki/Mentor) asks for those 50000.. **but in EUR**. Now I would like to exchange those currencies.

- A commonly suggested method is selling containers with USD, but now there does not appear to be any container in the game that can both hold USD yet be sold to traders non-empty.
- I can buy items from Peacekeeper, lets say *N-15 NVG* for 720 USD, selling them to Mechanic for 41888 RUB (58 RUB/USD) and using those to buy *288 EUR* from Skier. Effective total: 40% EUR/USD
- I can from now on only play NATO ammo and spend all my dollars on that, therefore keeping more Roubles to buy EUR for myself. Takes 10k rounds of *M855A1* (7 USD) and is possibly even less efficient, depending on my ability to make back each rounds value.

Is there any method that

1. *currently* works
2. without losing half the value?

Comment: I suppose Gunsmith option is already exhausted? Cause that was most cost-efficient way to generate EUR from RUR/USD

Comment: @Sanctus Sure, but that quest line is less than 10k EUR in quest rewards, even with Hideout bonus.

Comment: Then only way left is to use flea market to buy EUR from low-level players, who still have no idea where to use them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After completing the Gunsmith quest line, I had about 9000 EUR.

And so had everyone else - including those with no interest in using Peacekeepers offer to trade 50000 EUR for those Sniper skill levels.

So all that was left to to was: **flea market all loot for EUR instead of RUB, and buy all equipment for USD.** Those who got the Euros for free and have no use for them will pay a significant premium for not having to spend precious Roubles (which, unlike the other currencies, are usable for insurance). Even offers which are not the *cheapest* according the flea market sorting will be filled quickly.

(answer originally suggested in [comment by Sanctus](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/390037/#comment-548402))